# c# get the first ';' after parentheses

Tags: c#, split, substring

i feel dumb for asking a most likely silly question.

I am helping someone getting the results he wishes for his custom compiler that reads all lines of an xml file in one string so it will look like below, and since he wants it to "Support" to call variables inside the array worst case scenario would look like below:

```
"Var1 = [5,4,3,2]; Var2 = [2,8,6,Var1;4];"
```

What i need is to find the first ";" after "[" and "]" and split it, so i stand with this:

```
"Var1 = [5,4,3,2];
```

It will also have to support multiple "[", "]" for example:

```
"Var2 = [5,Var1,[4],2];"
```

EDIT: There may also be Data in between the last "]" and ";"
For example:

```
"Var2 = [5,[4],2]Var1;
```

What can i do here? Im kind of stuck.

Comment: Can't you just split the string on `];`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that there "can" be data inbetween "]" and ";"

Updated thread

Comment: If I had a penny for every time someone edits their question and totally changes the conditions... Anyway, sounds like Regex would be a good bet but I'm not particularly good with it.

Comment: `IndexOf(";",IndexOf("]")+1)`?

Comment: As i can see of requerements, you maybe better to parse string by symbols, and markup each time when symbols like ; and [ appears. And hold in memory flag "bracket was opened" so before get next value you must reset all flags (find all close brackets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
  string source = "Var1 = [5,4,3,2]; Var2 = [2,8,6,Var1;4];";

  // 1. final (or the only) chunk doesn't necessary contain '];':
  //   "abc" -> "abc"
  // 2. chunk has at least one symbol except '];'  
  string pattern = ".+?(][a-zA-Z0-9]*;|$)";

  var items = Regex
    .Matches(source, pattern) 
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, items));
```

Outcome:

```
  Var1 = [5,4,3,2]abc123;
   Var2 = [2,8,6,Var1;4];
```

Comment: Did you check the case for `]Var1;`?

Comment: I check. It works fine on this string `"Var1 = [5,4,3,2]; Var2 = [2,8,6,Var1;4]; Var3 = [5,4,3,2]; Var4 = [2,8,6,Var1;4]; Var5 = [5,Var1,[4],2]; Var6 = [5,[4],2]Var1;"`

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto : Thank you! I see the edit; the `pattern` should be modified then.

Comment: Thank you, it does exactly what its needed to.
Marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

```
^([^;]+);
```

This regex should work for all.
You can use it like here:

```
    string[] lines = 
            {
                "Var1 = [5,4,3,2]; Var2 = [2,8,6,Var1;4];",
                "Var2 = [5,[4],2]Var1; Var2 = [2,8,6,Var1;4];"
            };

        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^([^;]+);");

        foreach (string s in lines){
            Match match = pattern.Match(s);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
        }
```

The explanation is:

> ^ means starts with and is
>  [^;] anything but a semicolon
>   + means repeated one or more times and is
>  ; followed by a semicolon

This will find `Var1 = [5,4,3,2];` as well as `Var1 = [5,4,3,2];`

You can see the output [HERE](http://rextester.com/SKWLT68592)

Comment: An explanation of how to use it and how it works would be better

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string Extract(string str, char splitOn)
{
    var split = false;
    var count = 0;
    var bracketCount = 0;

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        count++;
        if (split && c == splitOn)
           return str.SubString(0, count);

        if (c == '[')
        {
             bracketCount++;
             split = false;
        }
        else if (c == ']')
        {
             bracketCount--;

             if (bracketCount == 0)
             { 
                 split = true;
             }
             else if (bracketCount < 0)
                 throw new FormatException(); //?
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```